# How to touch all files that are returned by a sorted ls?

Tags: linux, bash, touch, ls

If I have the following:

```
ls|sort -n
```

How would I touch all those files in the order of the sorted files? Something like:

```
ls|sort -n|touch
```

What would be the proper syntax? Note that I need to sort touch the files in the exact order they're being sorted -- as I'm trying to sort these files for a FAT reader with minimal metadata reading.

Comment: What about using `xargs` for invoking `touch`? I never use `ls` for scripting, and I'd prefer using `find` (probably with `-maxdepth 1`) instead with the `-exec` option.

Comment: @fluffy sure that would work -- how could that be done?

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -exec touch {} \;`? Also, `sort -n` seems to be unnecessary there. Take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580409/how-to-touch-files-recursively) for more (easily found by googling for `linux bash touch`).

Comment: @fluffy thanks -- I need the `sort -n` as I have filenames with numbers, so I want it as 1file, 2file,...10file, instead of 10file, 1file, 2file.

Comment: That command will eventually `touch` _all_ files (regular files, directories, etc) found by `find` -- I can't see why sorting and ordering matters in this case.

Comment: @fluffy it's for some weird FAT filesystem sorting thing. I have to touch them in a particular order to 're-sort' the output.

Comment: Aha, okay, I see it now. Not sure if `find` is able to sort (I believe it's unable), but then you probably need something like `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | sort -n -k2 -t/ | xargs touch` (where `-mindepth 1` excludes the current directory, `.`; `sort` is configured to sort by two the column where columns are delimited with `/` like `./1` and `./22` -- not sure if it requires more tweaking; `xargs` redirects each line of piped output to `touch`).

Comment: @fluffy it would be safer to put `-print0` option to `find`, `-z` to `sort`, and `-0` to `xargs` considering the case the filenames contain blank characters.

Comment: @tshiono Agree, still can't remember all that crazy stuff like NUL-delimiters to make it safe. I'm not sure, but if not using the flags you mentioned, would `xargs -I{} touch {}` be blank-chars-safe?

Comment: @fluffy it will be much safer but not enough. The filenames will be broken if the filename contains newline characters, which might be an edge case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -1tr | while read file; do touch "$file"; sleep 1; done
```

If you want to preserve distance in modification time from one file to the next then call this instead:

```
upmodstamps() {
    oldest_elapsed=$(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y "`ls -1tr|head -1`") ))
    for file in *; do
        oldstamp=$(stat -c %Y "$file")
        newstamp=$(( $oldstamp + $oldest_elapsed ))
        newstamp_fmt=$(date --date=@${newstamp} +'%Y%m%d%H%M.%S')
        touch -t ${newstamp_fmt} "$file"
    done
}
```

Note: `date` usage assumes GNU

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command

```
(ls|sort -n >> list.txt )    
touch $(cat list.txt)
```

OR

```
touch $(ls /path/to/dir | sort -n)
```

OR if you want to copy files instead of creating empty files use this command

```
cp list.txt ./DirectoryWhereYouWantToCopy
```

Comment: Where is the list.txt file??

Comment: list.txt contains list of files that you want to  create.I have updated the answer as well, please review it.

Comment: Nah, this will create a bunch of empty files.

Comment: So you mean you want to copy the files then use this command '''cp list.txt ./DirectoryWhereYouWantToCopy'''.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a few file name?
if you have file names with numbers as 1file, 10file, 11file .. 20file, then you need use `--general-numeric-sort`

```
ls | sort --general-numeric-sort --output=../workingDirectory/sortedFiles.txt
cat sortedFiles.txt
1file
10file
11file
12file
20file
```

and move sortedFile.txt into your working directory or where ever you want.

```
touch $(cat ../workingDirectory/sortedFiles.txt)
```

this will create empty files with the exact same name

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
touch $(ls | sort -n)
```